# Gitlab Runner Register on Termux with no root

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, termux

I trying to use gitlab runner on termux with no root so therefore no sudo so therefore in user-mode.

~ $ ./gitlab-runner register  --url https://MY_GITLAB_INSTANCE/git  --token MY_TOKEN

And getting error

Enter the GitLab instance URL (for example, https://gitlab.com/):

[https://MY_GITLAB_INSTANCE/git]:
ERROR: Verifying runner... failed                   runner=xxxxxxxxx status=couldn't execute POST against https://MY_GITLAB_INSTANCE/git/api/v4/runners/verify: Post "https://MY_GITLAB_INSTANCE/git/api/v4/runners/verify": dial tcp: lookup domain.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:42712->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to verify the runner.